# Review link on top bar is not showing on Meta site

Tags: discussion, review, meta, top-bar

I have 300+ reputation on Stack Overflow and following image is of my Stack Overflow site,

> [image]

As we can see that it is showing "Review" link on Stack Overflow site. Now I have 800+ reputation on Meta Site, here is the image,

> [image]

But on Meta it doesn't show me "Review" link. Do I require more reputation to gain the Review section? When Review link will be available for me on Meta?

Comment: You need at least 2k reputation to perform reviews: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there are neither First Posts nor Late Answers review tasks in Meta. So you need to earn at least 2000 reputation to see *review* link. While First Posts and Late Answers requires only [125 reputation on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down).